# print pdf horizontal half page half empty

Tags: pdf, printing

hi I want to print powerpoint slides (available as pdf) so that I will have one slide on each page but only half the page, so I have the other have for personal notes. 
Hase someone an idea on how to accomplish this without manually adding empty pages after each page?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bji0Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try printing from Acrobat and selecting a Custom Scale: 50% (adjust as needed). The Custom Scale option is found in the Page Size & Handling section of the Acrobat print dialog box.